# Dividing two double numbers in C++

Tags: c++, double, division

I have some experience in C++. I wrote the following code;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double mass_H;
double mass_S;
double Mass;
double S_Space;
double H2S_Conc;
double Conc;



// calculates the molecular mass of H2S, given the molecular mass of each element
void Molecular_Mass()
{
    Mass = ((2*mass_H)+(mass_S));
}

void H2S_Concentration()
{

    Conc = H2S_Conc/100;
    //c = H2S_Conc/1000000;
}


int main()
{

    cout << "Welcome to the H2S conversion .\n";
    cout << "Please enter molecular mass of Hydrogen: "<<endl;          // enter mass of hydrogen
    cin >> mass_H;
    cout << "Please enter molecular mass of Sulphur: " << endl;         // eneter mass of sulpher
    cin >> mass_S;

    Molecular_Mass();
    H2S_Concentration();                                                  // call molecular mass function
    S_Space = 22.41;  //Nm^3/kmol
    H2S_Conc = 292; // ppm v/v

    cout << "Molecular mass of H2S is: " << Mass << "kg/kmol"<< endl;
    cout << "Standard space occupied by a kmol at 0 degrees and 1 atm is: "<< S_Space << "Nm^3/kmol" <<  endl;
    cout << "H2S concentration is: " << H2S_Conc << "parts per million, which is a real concentration of: " << Conc <<endl;
```

The problem is when I compile and run, my value for Conc is 0. I am dividing two doubles, which I thought wasn't a problem.

I have had a look on google and I tried casting, by using a float but that didnt work either.

Can anyone tell me why it is returning zero

p.s ignore the rest of my crappy code ;)

Comment: Given you have `Conc = H2S_Conc/100;` in `H2S_Concentration` and set `HS2_Conc` *after* you call the `H2S_Concentration` function this is likely.  Did you mean to use `cin` on different variables?

Comment: You call H2S_Concentration before assigning H2S_Conc so technically it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Iverelo  OP uses global vars so no UB

Comment: It should not return `0` (it is a void but a global variable). The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @FirstStep it should

Comment: ah so I should call the function after the cin line? I will try now

Comment: @Tony it is taking the zero initialization value. And not your desired value. Make sure to assign your desired value to it before calling your function.

Comment: So, I called the H2S_Concentration() after the last line in my code, but it still returned the same 0

Comment: @FirstStep just seen this, do you mean where I declare it as a double, I must give it a value, say 0?

Comment: Did you see the answer on your question? by @User1234

Comment: @FirstStep yes thanks!

Comment: `Mass = ((2*mass_H)+(mass_S));` -- none of those parentheses is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is taking its default initialization value `0` since you did not assign any value to it before calling your function.

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// ..  
int main()
{
    // ..
    S_Space = 22.41;  //Nm^3/kmol
    H2S_Conc = 292; // ppm v/v

    // ..
    H2S_Concentration(); // call molecular mass function here

    //..
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: 
As recommended by [**πάντα ῥεῖ**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96), and since you are hard coding their values and not changing or will not be changing these values at run time, it is recommended to set both variables as constants, and initialize them with the wanted values like this:

```
const double S_Space = 22.41;  //Nm^3/kmol;
const double H2S_Conc = 292; // ppm v/v;
```

Comment: Shouldn't these be `const` actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you are right. I will edit my answer. But I would keep the design for the OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wouldn't it be even better to make them `constexpr`?

Answer (score 3):

Call `H2S_Concentration()` after these 2 lines :-

```
S_Space = 22.41;  //Nm^3/kmol
H2S_Conc = 292; // ppm v/v
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked!! Was it because, my function H2S_conc() was before the variable H2S_Conc was declared?

Comment: Small nitpick: Shouldn't these be `const double` variables and initialized at declaration?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i don't know, could it?

Comment: @TonyHibbert It was simply because  `H2S_Concentration()` call was before `H2S_Conc = 292`

Answer (score -2):

the error has been answered but you could edit your code a bit.
For example:

```
float H2S_Concentration()
{

    return H2S_Conc/100;
    //c = H2S_Conc/1000000;
}
```

then in the main

```
S_Space = 22.41;  //Nm^3/kmol
H2S_Conc = 292; // ppm v/v
Molecular_Mass();
Conc = H2S_Concentration();
```

Comment: Why `float` if OP uses `double` everywhere?

Comment: Thanks @Claudio Lopes ! Can you tell me why this is better than what I have? I am not being funny, just curious? :)

Comment: @TonyHibbert cause you should avoid using global vars as much as possible.

Comment: @Slava great thanks, so all my doubles should be 'const double' ?

Comment: @TonyHibbert Well, certainly not, only those that represent some chemical constants should be `const`.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with global constants.